# Run loop on group query with 2x foreach and then remove group key if condition is true for row

Tags: c#, visual-studio, foreach

I currently have been trying to run a loop on a group query with two `foreach`-statements like so:

```cs
var ResultsPO =
    from MyRowPo in dt.AsEnumerable()
    group MyRowPo by MyRowPo["Produktionsordre"];

foreach (var PoRows in ResultsPO)
{
    foreach (var RowsPO in PoRows)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(RowsPO["Lagerbeholdning_Antal"]) < 0)
        {
            RowsPO.Delete();
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

But it is only deleting the row where `RowsPO["Lagerbeholdning_Antal]" < 0`.

However, I want to delete all the rows in that group where that condition is true for a single row.

Also, I am using the break to run the query once, then find those groups where the condition is true or false, and then rerun the query again - this is if the condition is false then I want all the rows of column `["Lagerbeholdning_Antal"]` to update with value:
`["Lagerbeholdning_Antal"] = ["Lagerbeholdning_Antal"] - ["Demand"]` for all the next rows (but, this is done specifically where even another column value matches (etc. unique material id)).

Note: `Lagerbeholdning_Antal` means Amount in stock.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about this, but you have a break in the second loop, so it won't continue the execution and it is deleting exactly what you have indicated, since you are using RowsPO.Delete() and not PoRows.Delete(). But maybe I've not understood it properly

Comment: It is not possible to use PoRows.Delete() - ive tried this. Thanks

Comment: @Orokozaki, based on my test, If I delete the break code, I will get all the rows where the condition is true. Why do you add the break code? Besides, you can add some pictures in your question about your desired result, which will be better for us to know your question.